# Indirect effects in SEM for slightly complex path model

Tags: r-lavaan

I wanted to do calculate the direct and all indirect effects for a path analytic model. The path diagram has been given below:

[image: path model]

I am not sure of the code to use in [R]. There are examples of simple indirect effects and mediation models using coefficients a,b,etc and then using the := symbol. But I am not sure how to use that in this slightly more complex model. The standard code could be as below/.

```
#regression model
V3 ~ V1 + V2
V4 ~ V1 + V2 + V3
V5 ~ V4 + V5
```

I could attach coefficients to the independent variables above. How then do I write the code for the indirect function? Here we would have an indirect impact of V1 and V2 on V5, but no direct effect. How will that be coded? I us Lavaan. Is there another package? Will really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that is left for you is to set the labels in front of the variables. I will try to show you with a much simpler example.

Loading the packages and sample dataset:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(lavaan) # for the path analysis
require(semPlot) # To plot the path analysis

#Loading the data set (swiss is part of the Base R datasets). 
df <- swiss %>% 
  select(Fertility, Education, Infant.Mortality)

head(df)

             Fertility Education Infant.Mortality
Courtelary        80.2        12             22.2
Delemont          83.1         9             22.2
Franches-Mnt      92.5         5             20.2
Moutier           85.8         7             20.3
Neuveville        76.9        15             20.6
Porrentruy        76.1         7             26.6
```

Next you need to define the model. The model variable is separated into two parts: the regressions, and the mediation. Regressions are formed with `~` and mediations with `:=`. Please noticed that for every variable in the regression I attached the label with `*`. The labels are arbitrary by the user and can take almost any form. For example, here for `Infant.Mortality ~ FerMor*Fertility` I'm predicting the variable `Infant.Mortality` with the variable `Fertility`, and the label I gave was `FerMor`. 
Next, I use the labels to create the mediations. I created only one for this example `Path1 := FerMor * EDUMor * FerEDU`. `Path1` is the arbitrary name I gave to the mediation path and the `FerMor * EDUMor * FerEDU` is the mediation path I have chosen to specify.

I really recommend the use of comments. As the number of variables and mediations gets bigger it's really difficult to read the script.

```
Model <-'
# Regression
Infant.Mortality    ~   FerMor*Fertility
Infant.Mortality    ~   EDUMor*Education
Education   ~   FerEDU*Fertility

#Mediation
#Path 1 - Fertility -> Education -> Infant.Mortality
#         Fertility ->              Infant.Mortality
Path1 := FerMor * EDUMor * FerEDU
'
```

The last step is to run the model:

```
set.seed(1989)
fit <- sem(
  Model,
  data = scale(df),
  likelihood = "wishart",
  missing = 'ML',
  meanstructure = TRUE)
```

If you want to run a bootstrap you can add the arguments: `meanstructure = TRUE, se = "bootstrap", bootstrap = 5000`. If you're coming from SPSS/AMOS use `likelihood = "wishart"` to get the same results.

You can plot your model using `semPaths()`

```
semPaths(fit)
```

[image]

Lastly, to get the full model estimations (You can find the mediation at the end of the output in Defined Parameters) use the function `summary()`. I recommend adding the arguments `fit.measures = TRUE, standardize = TRUE`.

```
summary(fit, fit.measures = TRUE, standardize = TRUE)


lavaan (0.5-23.1097) converged normally after  13 iterations

  Number of observations                            47

  Number of missing patterns                         1

  Estimator                                         ML
  Minimum Function Test Statistic                0.000
  Degrees of freedom                                 0
  Minimum Function Value               0.0000000000000

Model test baseline model:

  Minimum Function Test Statistic               38.734
  Degrees of freedom                                 3
  P-value                                        0.000

User model versus baseline model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    1.000
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       1.000

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

  Loglikelihood user model (H0)               -178.771
  Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)       -178.771

  Number of free parameters                          7
  Akaike (AIC)                                 371.543
  Bayesian (BIC)                               384.343
  Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (BIC)          362.395

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.000
  90 Percent Confidence Interval          0.000  0.000
  P-value RMSEA <= 0.05                             NA

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.000

Parameter Estimates:

  Information                                 Observed
  Standard Errors                             Standard

Regressions:
                     Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  Infant.Mortality ~                                                      
    Fertlty (FrMr)      0.627    0.173    3.623    0.000    0.627    0.627
    Educatn (EDUM)      0.317    0.173    1.831    0.067    0.317    0.317
  Education ~                                                             
    Fertlty (FEDU)     -0.664    0.110   -6.019    0.000   -0.664   -0.664

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .Infant.Mortlty   -0.000    0.128   -0.000    1.000   -0.000   -0.000
   .Education         0.000    0.109    0.000    1.000    0.000    0.000

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .Infant.Mortlty    0.754    0.157    4.796    0.000    0.754    0.770
   .Education         0.547    0.114    4.796    0.000    0.547    0.559

Defined Parameters:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
    Path1            -0.132    0.102   -1.288    0.198   -0.132   -0.132
```

You can visit [here](http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/mediation.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar question. In lavaan you have to write syntax for indirect and total effects by hand using tracing rules, Duncan's rules or direct effects matrix multiplication (see a general explanation in Maruyama, Basics of Structural Equation Modeling).

You can write some code to generate that syntax, here's my attempt [here](https://www.kaggle.com/rimantasrauleckas/kernel74193b262d) and the summary below. It uses symbolic matrix library in r and in python. Hope you can adapt the code or the idea to your needs.

First I describe the measurement and structural model without explicit indirect or total effects and run it:

```
model.cfa <- "quality =~ Q068_1 + Q068_4
              delivery  =~ Q069_2 + Q069_5
              flexibility  =~ Q071_1 + Q071_4 + Q071_5
              costs   =~ Q070_1 + Q070_2 + Q070_3
              innovation =~ Q072_1 + Q072_3 + Q072_2"

model.sem_1a <- paste(model.cfa, "
              delivery ~ quality
              flexibility ~ delivery
              costs ~ flexibility
              innovation ~ costs")

fit.sem_1a <- sem(model.sem_1a, data = dataset, missing = "fiml")
summary(fit.sem_1a, fit.measures = T, standardized = T, rsquare = T)
```

Then I get the matrix of standardized direct effects coefficients and transpose it to make dependent variables appear in columns and independents in rows:

```
# Get matrix of beta coefficients from lavInspect function:
mtx <- lavInspect(fit.sem_1a, what = "std", add.labels = TRUE, add.class = TRUE,
           list.by.group = TRUE,
           drop.list.single.group = TRUE)$beta

m <- t(mtx)  # transpose matrix
```

The output of m matrix:

```
            qualty delvry flxblt costs innvtn
quality          0   0.52  0.000 0.000  0.000
delivery         0   0.00  0.412 0.000  0.000
flexibility      0   0.00  0.000 0.309  0.000
costs            0   0.00  0.000 0.000  0.442
innovation       0   0.00  0.000 0.000  0.000
```

Then I switch to rSymPy package - implementation of python Sympy library in r - and recreate the matrix of direct coefficients by replacing the numerical values of the coefficients to string labels:

```
rn <- rownames(m)
cn <- colnames(m)
library(rSymPy)
symbolic_mtrx <- matrix(nrow=length(rownames(m)), ncol=length(colnames(m)))             # initialize empty symbolic matrix with correct dimensions

# Now fill in the matrix with 'z' for zero elements and abbreviations for non-zero path coefficients 

for (i in 1:length(rownames(m))){
  for (j in 1:length(colnames(m))){
    symbolic_mtrx[i,j]<-noquote('z')      # noquote not necessary
    if (m[i,j]!=0) {
      #print(m[i,j])
      l<-paste0(substr(rownames(m)[i],1,1),substr(colnames(m)[j],1,1))          # create a name for a coefficient from first letter of each construct name
      symbolic_mtrx[i,j]<-noquote(l)
    }
  }
}

symbolic_mtrx   # print the symbolic matrix
```

The output from symbolic_mtrx:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "z"  "qd" "z"  "z"  "z" 
[2,] "z"  "z"  "df" "z"  "z" 
[3,] "z"  "z"  "z"  "fc" "z" 
[4,] "z"  "z"  "z"  "z"  "ci"
[5,] "z"  "z"  "z"  "z"  "z"
```

Due to my inability to perform matrix multiplication in rSymPy in r I switched to python and multiply the symbolic matrix as many times as necessary:

````
library(reticulate)

```{python}

from sympy import Matrix

rsm_direct = Matrix(r.symbolic_mtrx)           #get direct effects matrix from r
rsm_indirect_1 = rsm_direct*rsm_direct         # get first order indirect effects by multiplication
rsm_indirect_2 = rsm_indirect_1*rsm_direct     # get second order indirect effects by multiplication. Would be nice to know in advance how many levels of indirect effects exist.
rsm_total_indirect = rsm_indirect_1 + rsm_indirect_2     # sum of first and second order indirect effects
rsm_total = rsm_total_indirect + rsm_direct    # get total effects

```
````

The output from rsm_total (total effects formula), where z means zero coefficient:

```
Matrix([[qd*z + 4*z**2 + z*(df*qd + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z, 2*qd*z + qd*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + qd + 3*z**2 + z*(df*qd + 4*z**2) + z*(2*qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2), df*qd + df*(2*qd*z + 3*z**2) + 4*z**2 + z*(df*qd + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z, fc*z + fc*(df*qd + 4*z**2) + qd*z + 3*z**2 + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z, ci*z + ci*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + qd*z + 3*z**2 + z*(df*qd + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z], [df*z + 4*z**2 + z*(df*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z, df*z + qd*z + qd*(df*z + 4*z**2) + 3*z**2 + z*(df*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(2*df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z, 2*df*z + df*(df*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + df + 3*z**2 + z*(df*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2), df*fc + fc*(2*df*z + 3*z**2) + 4*z**2 + z*(df*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z, ci*z + ci*(df*fc + 4*z**2) + df*z + 3*z**2 + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z], [fc*z + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z, fc*z + qd*z + qd*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + 3*z**2 + z*(ci*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(2*fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z, df*z + df*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + fc*z + 3*z**2 + z*(ci*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z, 2*fc*z + fc*(df*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + fc + 3*z**2 + z*(ci*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2), ci*fc + ci*(2*fc*z + 3*z**2) + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z], [ci*z + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*ci*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z, ci*z + qd*z + qd*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + 3*z**2 + z*(2*ci*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z, ci*z + df*z + df*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + 3*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*ci*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z, ci*z + fc*z + fc*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + 3*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*ci*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z, 2*ci*z + ci*(ci*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + ci + 3*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*ci*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2)], [5*z**3 + 5*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z, 5*qd*z**2 + qd*z + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z, df*z + df*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + 5*z**3 + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z, fc*z + fc*(df*z + 4*z**2) + 5*z**3 + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z, ci*z + ci*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + 5*z**3 + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z]])
```

Create the syntax for indirect and total effects based on text strings in multiplied symbolic matrix (still in python, but not necessarily):

````
```{python}
l=len(r.rn)                          # number of matrix rows, taken from r object
total_effects_syntax = str()         # initialize empty string for syntax 
for i,rname in enumerate(r.rn):      # both row index and row elements in matrix are needed, thefore use of enumerate()
  for j,cname in enumerate(r.cn):    # now traverse through columns
    if i!=j:                         # exclude path coefficients that go from construct to itself 
        total_effects_syntax+= " "+rname[0]+cname[0]+"_total:= "+str(rsm_total[i*l+j]) + " \n "         # create a string for lavaan total effects

# Now indicate that z means zero: 
total_effects_syntax = "z:=0"  + " \n" + total_effects_syntax + " "
print(total_effects_syntax)
```
````

The output is the syntax for total effects that will be inserted back to the description of the structural model (the output cleaned by hand for display purposes):

```
z:=0 
 qd_total:= 2*qd*z + qd*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + qd + 3*z**2 + z*(df*qd + 4*z**2) + z*(2*qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) 
  qf_total:= df*qd + df*(2*qd*z + 3*z**2) + 4*z**2 + z*(df*qd + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z 
  qc_total:= fc*z + fc*(df*qd + 4*z**2) + qd*z + 3*z**2 + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z 
  qi_total:= ci*z + ci*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + qd*z + 3*z**2 + z*(df*qd + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z 
  dq_total:= df*z + 4*z**2 + z*(df*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z 
  df_total:= 2*df*z + df*(df*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + df + 3*z**2 + z*(df*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) 
  dc_total:= df*fc + fc*(2*df*z + 3*z**2) + 4*z**2 + z*(df*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z 
  di_total:= ci*z + ci*(df*fc + 4*z**2) + df*z + 3*z**2 + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z 
  fq_total:= fc*z + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z 
  fd_total:= fc*z + qd*z + qd*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + 3*z**2 + z*(ci*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(2*fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z 
  fc_total:= 2*fc*z + fc*(df*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + fc + 3*z**2 + z*(ci*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) 
  fi_total:= ci*fc + ci*(2*fc*z + 3*z**2) + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z 
  cq_total:= ci*z + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*ci*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z 
  cd_total:= ci*z + qd*z + qd*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + 3*z**2 + z*(2*ci*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z 
  cf_total:= ci*z + df*z + df*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + 3*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*ci*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z 
  ci_total:= 2*ci*z + ci*(ci*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + ci + 3*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*ci*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) 
  iq_total:= 5*z**3 + 5*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z 
  id_total:= 5*qd*z**2 + qd*z + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z 
  if_total:= df*z + df*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + 5*z**3 + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z 
  ic_total:= fc*z + fc*(df*z + 4*z**2) + 5*z**3 + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z
```

Finally, switching back to r and running the model for the second time, but now with the syntax for total effects added to the model definition:

```
model.sem_1a <- paste(model.cfa, "
              delivery ~ qd*quality
              flexibility ~ df*delivery
              costs ~ fc*flexibility
              innovation ~ ci*costs
              ", py$total_effects_syntax)

fit.sem_1a <- sem(model.sem_1a, data = dataset, missing = "fiml")
summary(fit.sem_1a, fit.measures = T, standardized = T, rsquare = T)
```

Here's the model (model.sem_1a) description with the syntax for total effects added, our final goal:

```
quality =~ Q068_1 + Q068_4
delivery  =~ Q069_2 + Q069_5
flexibility  =~ Q071_1 + Q071_4 + Q071_5
costs   =~ Q070_1 + Q070_2 + Q070_3
innovation =~ Q072_1 + Q072_3 + Q072_2
delivery ~ qd*quality
flexibility ~ df*delivery
costs ~ fc*flexibility
innovation ~ ci*costs
z:=0
qd_total:= 2*qd*z + qd*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + qd + 3*z**2 + z*(df*qd + 4*z**2) + z*(2*qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2)
qf_total:= df*qd + df*(2*qd*z + 3*z**2) + 4*z**2 + z*(df*qd + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z
qc_total:= fc*z + fc*(df*qd + 4*z**2) + qd*z + 3*z**2 + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z
qi_total:= ci*z + ci*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + qd*z + 3*z**2 + z*(df*qd + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*qd*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z
dq_total:= df*z + 4*z**2 + z*(df*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z
df_total:= 2*df*z + df*(df*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + df + 3*z**2 + z*(df*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2)
dc_total:= df*fc + fc*(2*df*z + 3*z**2) + 4*z**2 + z*(df*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z
di_total:= ci*z + ci*(df*fc + 4*z**2) + df*z + 3*z**2 + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z
fq_total:= fc*z + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z
fd_total:= fc*z + qd*z + qd*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + 3*z**2 + z*(ci*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(2*fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(df*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z
fc_total:= 2*fc*z + fc*(df*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + fc + 3*z**2 + z*(ci*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2)
fi_total:= ci*fc + ci*(2*fc*z + 3*z**2) + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*fc + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(fc*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z
cq_total:= ci*z + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*ci*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z
cd_total:= ci*z + qd*z + qd*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + 3*z**2 + z*(2*ci*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + z
cf_total:= ci*z + df*z + df*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2) + 3*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*ci*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + z
ci_total:= 2*ci*z + ci*(ci*z + fc*z + 3*z**2) + ci + 3*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(2*ci*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + df*z + 3*z**2) + z*(ci*z + qd*z + 3*z**2)
iq_total:= 5*z**3 + 5*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z
id_total:= 5*qd*z**2 + qd*z + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z \n  if_total:= df*z + df*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + 5*z**3 + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(df*z + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z
ic_total:= fc*z + fc*(df*z + 4*z**2) + 5*z**3 + 4*z**2 + z*(ci*z + 4*z**2) + z*(fc*z + 4*z**2) + z*(qd*z + 4*z**2) + z
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Best practice is to include the code in your answer. This way your answer remains useful even if the external link breaks.